# Application-defined or object-define error when using Range

Tags: vba, excel

The 2nd line of code below is throwing the abovementioned error:

```
Dim rng As String
rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(4000, 302)).Address
```

**302nd column is fixed and is the end column of the selection that I must copy.*

What I find odd is replacing 302 with **255 or below** gets rid of the error and enables my program to work.

Another thing I do not understand is; using the immediate window ---- having 255 on the column parameter prints **$A$2:$IU$4000**, as it should. However, replacing it with **256** throws **$2:$4000** whereas I believe it should be **$A$2:$IV$4000**. Any number above results to the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you're using Excel<=2003, It only supports column up to `IV` (which should be 256), so 302 would be out-of-range.

Comment: Are you using xl2003 which only has 256 columns? Hence the code works fine with 255 or less, but 302 blows the column limit

Comment: And since `IV`(256) is the last column, selecting `$A$2:$IV$4000` is actually seleting `$2:$4000` (full row selection).

Comment: @Passerby and brettdj, you guys were both right. Thanks! I now feel silly missing something that seems so basic

Comment: Maybe one of the comments (@Passerby?) should be posted as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, extending from comment:

For your first question, since you're using Excel<=2003 (from comment), your "tail" column would be `IV`, which is #256,

so your largest available column number is 256, and calling `Cells(4000,302)` would be out-of-range.

---

For your second question, since you're using Excel<=2003, one row can only contain up to 256 columns,

so selecting `A2:IV4000` (row #2 to #4000, col #1 to #256) is effectively equals to selecting `2:4000` (full row selection, row #2 to #4000), and Excel "shorten" that address for you.